# Mock (Moq) Bot call with Microsoft Bot SDK throwing System.ArgumentException : Unsupported expression

Tags: c#, unit-testing, botframework

I have developed a bot that can push messages to a bot installed in MS Teams. It was developed using Microsoft Bot SDK v4 and works with an api.

The functionality works as I want. I am now in the process of writing unit tests to cover the functions in my controller and I need to moq certain activity to make the tests work and one of those being ContinueConversationAsync.

The following is the Post operation in my controller. Using a person's email address it gets their details from Microsoft Graph, it looks up the Conversation Reference in a Cosmos DB, captured when the bot is installed, and uses the reference to send a proactive message to the person from the bot.

```
[HttpPost("teams")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostTeams([FromBody]ProactiveMessageModel message)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //return BadRequest(ModelState);
        return ValidationProblem();
    }

    _message = message.Message;
    List<string> missedEmails = new List<string>();
    List<GraphUserDetailModel> graphUsers = await _microsoftGraphService.GetGraphUserDetails(message.Email.ToObject<List<string>>(), missedEmails);
    string partitionId = _environment.EnvironmentName == "Development" ? "emulator" : "msteams";
    string container = "Convo";

    foreach (GraphUserDetailModel graphUser in graphUsers)
    {
        dynamic result = await _cosmosDBService.GetItemAsync(graphUser.UserId, partitionId, container);
        if (result != null)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(await _cosmosDBService.StripMeta(result));
            ConversationReference conversationReference = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConversationReference>(json);
            await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));
        }
        else
        {
            missedEmails.Add(graphUser.Email);
        }
    }

    // Sent the rest of the messages by email
    if (missedEmails.Count > 0)
    {
        _sendEmailService.SendEmail(missedEmails, message.Subject, message.Message);
    }

    // Let the caller know proactive messages have been sent
    return new ContentResult()
    {
        Content = "<html><body><h1>The message: [" + _message + "] has been sent via Teams.</h1></body></html>",
        ContentType = "text/html",
        StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
    };
}
```

In the code for my unit test I need to mock the call to Microsoft Graph, the call to Cosmos and the call to the bot. I have read up on TestAdapter, but don't think it is relevant here as the examples I've seen replace the bot communication from within the test itself. This is my test (using xUnit):

```
[Fact]
public async void PostTeams_ReturnsAViewResult_ContainingTheMessageSent()
{
    // Arrange
    _microsoftGraphService.Setup(mock => mock.GetGraphUserDetails(It.IsAny<List<string>>(), It.IsAny<List<string>>())).ReturnsAsync(GetUserDetails());
    _cosmosDBService.Setup(repo => repo.GetItemAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(GetConversationReference());
    _adapter.Setup(bot => ((TestAdapter)bot).ContinueConversationAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Activity>(), It.IsAny<BotCallbackHandler>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Verifiable();

    NotifyController controller = new NotifyController(_adapter.Object, _configuration, _cosmosDBService.Object, _microsoftGraphService.Object, _environment.Object, _sendGridEmailService.Object, _teamsChannelService.Object)
    {
        ControllerContext = _controllerContext
    };

    // Act
    var result = await controller.PostTeams(_proactiveMessageModel);

    // Assert
    var contentResult = Assert.IsType<ContentResult>(result);
    Assert.Contains("Test message", contentResult.Content);
}
```

When I get to the _adapter.Setup line my code is throwing the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException : Unsupported expression: (TestAdapter)bot
```

I don't know what I need to do to mock the call to the bot, can anyone help please?

Comment: What is the type of `_adapter`? Also is this `((BotAdapter)_adapter)` casting necessary in your actual code?

Comment: _adapter is IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, that is required for the constructor of the controller to replicate DI.

It appears necessary because without mocking the call I get another exception when running that line in the controller.

Comment: The cast is necessary in the code above. I based my bot on the Microsoft Echo bot example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Cvs

The bot object is created with an IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter delivered by DI. To use the object you cast it to the BotAdapter that contains the code to process the actions available in the interface.

In my test I also create an IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter in my constructor via DI and when I mock the setup I am trying to cast it to either a BotAdpater or TestAdapter.

Comment: You can define a proxy class where you can typecast to BotAdapter which also have DI of IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter. Now in your business logic you can inject this proxy class (so that you don't need to type case to anything in your business logic). Also in your unit test, you can provide the mock of this proxy object.

Comment: let me know if your thought for above suggestion?

Comment: @user1672994 your suggestion worked and solved my issue. Thanks for your help.